# Python: Load a csv file in a DataFrame with exception for string and list comma separator

Tags: python, pandas, replace, dataframe

I have a particular problem with a very badly formated csv file
structured with comma as separator but also in some column field strings and lists that contain commas also.

Is there a way in Python with or without Pandas to load in a DataFrame a csv
with such statement? : separate in a new column whenever there is a ,(comma) unless it is between "[]" or ""

Or  a method to replace the comma between [ ] and "" by a space this should work as well.

Here is an example of the structure (with of course many more rows and columns in the original one):

What I have:

```
column1,column2,column3,column.4
375,"string1","string.2",["string3"]
320,"string4, string5","string6",500
345,"string7",["string8", "string9"],"string10"
```

What I want:

```
   column1   column2           column3                 column.4
1   375   "string1"           "string.2"              ["string3"]
2   320   "string4, string5"  "string6"                500
3   345   "string7"           ["string8", "string9"]  "string10"
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", quotechar='"')
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep=(','), quotechar='"', doublequote=True)
```

But each time the same error pop up:

```
pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 18 fields in line 3, saw 19
```

As it is still separating for commas in lists

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Yes, I'd use a regex for that , for each line.

Comment: I think the only thing higher precedence than the `sep` is the `quotechar`.  Can you have any control over the input?  Could you escape the quotes delimiting the `stringN`s and put unescaped quotes around the other items?

Comment: Hi, Yes I can manipulate the input file. If I have to use some regex to replace or reformat the file I can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole trick that makes this work on your toy dataset is the assumption that if an apostrophe appears and there's a space after it, don't replace that apostrophe with a temporary delimiter `|`.  For example, take `"string4, string5"` - if this can ever be `"string4,string5"` (with space removed), the below 'trick' might not be suitable.  Hope it helps though.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

## data in 'myfile.csv' looks like this##
##column1,column2,column3,column.4
##375,"string1","string.2",["string3"]
##320,"string4, string5","string6",500
##345,"string7",["string8", "string9"],"string10"

new_data = []
with open(r'C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\myfile.csv') as f:
  f_as_string = f.read()
  res = re.sub(',(?!\s)', '|', f_as_string)
  for i in res.split('\n'):
    new_data.append(i.split('|'))


df = pd.DataFrame(data=new_data[1:], columns=new_data[0])

## Produces this dataframe literally retaining quotes
##  column1             column2                 column3     column.4
##0     375           "string1"              "string.2"  ["string3"]
##1     320  "string4, string5"               "string6"          500
##2     345           "string7"  ["string8", "string9"]   "string10"
```